# Add a value to localstorage and not replacing it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

I want the value from ngStorage to be added to locastorage addIdMatch. whereas in my code, it replaces an already existing value when I refresh the page.

```
 $scope.addIdMatch = function(infoMatchHomeTeam, infoMatchGoalHomeTeam, infoMatchGoalAwayTeam, infoMatchAwayTeam) {
    $i = $i +1
    $localStorage[$i] = {
      infoMatchHomeTeam, infoMatchGoalHomeTeam, infoMatchGoalAwayTeam, infoMatchAwayTeam
    }
  };
```

Comment: where is `$i` initialized?  more than likely, you are starting at `0` when you reload, instead of starting at the length of the items already in `$localStorage`.

Comment: oh thank, I replaced $i = $i + 1 by $i = localStorage.length +1